# CHtml::radioButtonList validation in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-chtml

Im using Chtml for one of my form in my Yii project.

I have implemented radioButton in that form , i.e

```
   <?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList('asset', 'asset', $listAsset, array('uncheckValue'=>null));?>
```

how can I do validation for this?

Comment: use model name. When you submit form the model attributes are validated and errors are returned if any. please have a look at this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/351/working-with-radiobutton-list/

Comment: then i think you to have to use jquery instead.

Comment: you don't want use model name in form?

Comment: @Rafay I used client side validation.thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we don't want use model name in form mean try the following steps

after assign the attribute values you can assign the post values to model attributes

once you specified the validation in MODEL's rules function, you can use the following steps.

**example :**

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['model']; //if you use model name in other fields  

$model->asset = $_POST['asset'];
```